# CSS Grid - Creating a one column layout with margins with centered content whose content is left-aligned

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

On mobile devices, I want a centered single column layout with margins on either side. The content within the column is a label followed by a MUI form field (which is wrapped in a `<span>`). I want the label and the content below it to be left-aligned flush with each other.

I know the exact width of the component and if the label is long, I'd like it to wrap around.

[image]

Finally, the number of rows here is dynamic so I don't know exactly how many rows there will be to use `grid-template-areas`.  I create a grid layout but I can't seem to lay out anything into columns much less do the other things that I want to achieve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: 'side content side';
}

.field {
  grid-area: content;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.label {
  hyphens: auto; /* not sure which of these to use to wrap the longer labels */
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.other-data {
  display: block; /* this is controlled by an external MUI style so can't be changed */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="field">
    <span class="label">Label 1</span>
    <span class="other-data">Some other stuff 1</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <span class="label">Label 2</span>
    <span class="other-data">Some other stuff 2</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <!-- Try with a long label -->
    <span class="label">Label 3 - Longer label</span>
    <span class="other-data">Some other stuff 3</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <span class="label">Label 4</span>
    <span class="other-data">Some other stuff 4</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot easier than you think. You don’t need a grid. Just give your wrapper a fixed `width: 300px;` then center it with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.field {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.other-data {
  display: block; /* this is controlled by an external MUI style so can't be changed */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="field">
    <span class="label">Label 1</span>
    <span class="other-data">Some other stuff 1</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <span class="label">Label 2</span>
    <span class="other-data">Some other stuff 2</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <!-- Try with a long label -->
    <span class="label">Label 3 - A really long label should wrap like this a really long label should wrap like this a really long label should wrap like this</span>
    <span class="other-data">Some other stuff 3</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <span class="label">Label 4</span>
    <span class="other-data">Some other stuff 4</span>
  </div>

</div>
```